Counting matching pairs of letters in lists of bigrams in Power Query M
Having had great success with my previous question about bigram decomposition in M, I am now encountering a new problem.
I am trying to count the matching pairs between two lists of bigrams and both methods I have tried sometimes undercount and I cannot put my finger on why exactly.
As an example, the matches between {"He","el","ll","lo"} and {"He","el","lo"} correctly counts 3 matches (well, 6, but I am intentionally doubling the count within the functions), whereas {"He","el","ll","lo"} and {"Hi","il","lo"} incorrectly counts 0 matches instead of 1.
I am using List.Sort() for inputs prior to implementation, though the issue is invariant to the sorting.
Both my functions are based on the counter within the java implementation of the Dice similarity page in wikibooks
snippet here:
int matches = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < n && j < m)
    {
        if (sPairs[i] == tPairs[j])
        {
            matches += 2;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else if (sPairs[i] < tPairs[j])
            i++;
        else
            j++;
    }

My initial crack at it resulted in a recursive function:
(x as list, y as list, i as number, j as number, matches) as number => 
let 
    matcher = if x{i} = y{j} then matches + 2 else matches,
    ineq = if x{i} < y{j} then 1 else 0,
    Check = if i = List.Count(x) - 1 or j = List.Count(y) - 1 then matcher
            else if matcher > matches then @Counter1(x,y,i+1,j+1,matcher)
            else if ineq = 1 then @Counter1(x,y,i+1,j,matcher)
            else @Counter1(x,y,i,j+1,matcher)
in Check

In order to avoid the recursion due to potential speed issues, I also had copilot write me a function using list.accumulate
(x as list, y as list) as number => 
let 
    n = List.Count(x),
    m = List.Count(y),
    matches = List.Accumulate(
        {0..n-1},
        [i = 0, j = 0, matches = 0],
        (state, current) =>
            if state[i] < n and state[j] < m then
                if x{state[i]} = y{state[j]} then
                    [i = state[i] + 1, j = state[j] + 1, matches = state[matches] + 2]
                else if x{state[i]} < y{state[j]} then
                    [i = state[i] + 1, j = state[j], matches = state[matches]]
                else
                    [i = state[i], j = state[j] + 1, matches = state[matches]]
            else
                state
    )[matches]
in
    matches

From what I can see, both functions give identical outputs, and the second definitely feels faster, though this means they also both give that undercounting issue.
The only thing that comes to mind is that the java code I adapted makes use of the binary representation of the letter pairs to compare them whereas I'm unsure as to how M is comparing the letter pairs in my functions.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

let list1= {"He","el","ll","lo"}, //alternatively Source[Column1]
list2={"He","el","lo"} , //alternatively Source[Column2]
matching_list = List.Intersect({list1,list2}), // list of matches
count_matching=List.Count(List.Intersect({list1,list2}))  // count of matches
in count_matching


I think your coding skills are much better than mine but I'll have a crack at it anyway. Being a lazy person I have chosen the simplest approach I can think of, expanding the second list of bigrams over every bigram from the first list and counting matches. I'm sure it can be done in an even simpler way but that's my dumbed down way of working with Power Query.
I just realised that it might lead to over-counting in certain circumstances and might not be what you wanted in the first place.
let
    // Load the original table, subsitute other sources
    Source = Table.FromRecords({
        [Column1 = "He", Column2 = "Hi"],
        [Column1 = "el", Column2 = "il"],
        [Column1 = "ll", Column2 = "lo"],
        [Column1 = "lo", Column2 = null]
    }),

    // Separate Column1 and Column2 into two tables
    Table1 = Table.SelectColumns(Source, {"Column1"}),
    Table2 = Table.SelectColumns(Source, {"Column2"}),

    // Remove null values from Table2, not strictly required
    Table2NonNull = Table.SelectRows(Table2, each [Column2] <> null),

    // Create a custom column in Table1 to add all rows of Table2 to each row of Table1
    CrossJoin = Table.AddColumn(Table1, "Column2", each Table2NonNull[Column2]),

    // Expand the new column to create the cross join effect
    ExpandedTable = Table.ExpandListColumn(CrossJoin, "Column2"),
    // Count matches
    Custom = Table.AddColumn(ExpandedTable, "Custom", each if [Column1]=[Column2] then 1 else 0),
    // Sum all ones in the column
    TotalMatchCount = List.Sum(Custom[Custom])
in
    TotalMatchCount

